# Centering chapter/section/subsection

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to center my chapters/sections/subsections.

I have used the following:

```
\newcommand{\cchapter}[1]{\chapter[#1]{\centering #1}}
\newcommand{\ssection}[1]{\section[#1]{\centering #1}}
\newcommand{\ssubsection}[1]{\subsection[#1]{\centering #1}}
```

This seems to work for chapter, but not for section and subsection. What is wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) have a look at the `titlesec` package

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your definition will work for sections and subsections, but not for chapters and has a potential drawback in that you loose control over the optional argument for the sectional units; with your definitions, the optional argument will always be equal to the mandatory argument and that might not be desirable.

Here's one option using the [`sectsty`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\allsectionsfont{\centering}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Test Subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here's now an option using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[center]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Test Subsection}

\end{document}
```

These solution horizontally centers the headings for all sectional units; the packages provides commands to modify the formatting on a *per-level* basis. Here's the code (using `sectsty`) to apply the change only to chapters, sections and subsections:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\chapterfont{\centering}
\sectionfont{\centering}
\subsectionfont{\centering}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Test Subsection}
```

\end{document}

Comment: Amazing. I've gone through the `titlesec.pdf` twice, and couldn't find that simple `\usepackage[center]{titlesec}` command, until I've found your answer... Can you please tell me where is this documented?

Comment: What if we want to such thing in an `article` document?