# How can I put the section or chapter number in the section or chapter title

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering

I am using the university thesis template which has the chapter/section headings setup in a way that prevents using `hyperref`.  The problem is they use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` so there is no section number preceding the chapter/section title.  They want the heading to display using this format both in the TOC and at the beginning of the chapter:

> Chapter 1: Sample Chapter Heading

The way they implement this means we must manually number the chapters and it also breaks `hyperref`.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centerline {\normalsize Table of Contents}}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand\cftloftitlefont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\cftlottitlefont{\normalsize}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\centering\normalsize}

% this breaks their chapter/toc settings
% \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage

%\section{\protect \centering Chapter 7: Sample Title}
\section{\protect Chapter 7: Sample Title}
chapter text goes here
\end{document}
```

I am sure latex has the ability to create chapter/section heading in this format while using counters but I am struggling to get it to work.  How can I use the built in counters (preferably the section counter since each section is a chapter in their setup) to natively create this format of the table of contents which would also allow the use of `hyperref`?

**EDIT 1:**
I did find that the `\centering` flag in the section titles was conflicting with hyperref.  Following [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107282/61946) [two](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103290/61946) responses (thanks @GonzaloMedina), I was able to implement the centering and the desired font size using the following

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\centering\normalsize\selectfont}
```

in the preamble which allowed me to remove the `\centering` flag from the section title:

```
%\section{\protect \centering Chapter 7: Sample Title}
\section{\protect Chapter 7: Sample Title}
```

I added these modifications (commenting out the original) in the MWE.

[image: toc image]

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your question is. You can use `hyperref` by removing `\protect \centering`. To get the right chapter labels, use `\renewcommand\thesection{Chapter \arabic{section}:}`

Comment: @alaferg, `\renewcommand\thesection{Chapter \arabic{section}:}` was exactly what I needed.  Thank you!  (can you add that as an answer so I can accept that?)

Comment: sure, no prob :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the right chapter labels, use

```
\renewcommand\thesection{Chapter \arabic{section}:}
```

**EDIT**
@Werner makes an excellent point. Here's a better approach (may need to play around with the spacing) which won't mess up your labels and references. To change TOC appearance

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{Chapter }
\renewcommand{\cftsecnumwidth}{5.75em}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{:}
```

To change section heading inside doc

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\Large}{Chapter \arabic{section}:}{0.5em}{}
```

Comment: Hmmm, this will also affect reference made to chapters, not just the labels in the ToC. So, `See \ref{ch:label}.` will turn into `See Chapter 2:.`, say... not really ideal.

Comment: I think, this should edited and improved