# How can I properly center my table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, titletoc

I am trying to typeset a book in LaTeX, but I'm having trouble formatting my table of contents. I've been able to center my title and chapter numbers successfully, but I can't figure out how to center the chapter titles and the pages on which chapters start.

This code reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{titletoc, tocloft, lipsum, fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}

% Centers the table of contents title:
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}

% Eliminates the space between the chapter title and the page number:
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfillnum}[1]{~$\cdot$~#1\cftparfillskip\par} 
% ^Puts a small dot between the chapter and the page number.

% Here's where I need help:
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\\} 
% ^Puts the chapter title below the chapter number. How do I increase this space?
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\centering} 
% ^Centers the chapter numbers. How do I center the chapter titles/pages?

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter Title}
\lipsum
\chapter{Another Chapter Title}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Here's a picture:

[image]

This is my first time asking a question, so let me know if my MWE is unclear or if I need to provide more information. Thanks!

Comment: is that answering a part from your question
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107281/centering-chapter-section-subsection

Comment: @AhmedSokar: Not quite! Sectsty isn't compatible with KOMA-Script, and the solution in that question only centers chapter titles in the body of the document. I'm trying to center chapter titles in the table of contents. Thank you for the suggestion, though!

Comment: `titletoc` and `tocloft` are incompatible with KOMA-script as well.

Comment: sigh: KOMA, titletoc and tocloft ... oh my -- use **one** of them, but not all of them!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution! Huzzah!

As Christian Hupfer and Johannes_B pointed out in the comments, combining `scrbook` with `tocloft` and `titletoc` was a terrible idea; as such, I abandoned my original approach completely and switched my document class to `memoir`. I suspect such radical revision to solve a single problem is akin to nuking fleas, so I'll leave this question open because there's probably a more elegant solution.

Anyway, here's what I came up with:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\let\ordinal\relax
\usepackage{fmtcount}
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfillnum}[1]{~$\cdot$~#1\cftparfillskip\par}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{}

% This code centers the table of contents title.
\renewcommand*{\printtoctitle}[1]{\centering#1} 

% This code centers the rest of my table of contents. Huzzah!
\setrmarg{0em}
\setlength\cftchapternumwidth{0pt}
\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{\hfil#1\hfil\strut\par\nopagebreak\hfil}

\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{10pt} % Controls distance between TOC entries.

\linespread{1.25}\selectfont % Controls line-spacing in the whole document. 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{Title}
\chapter{Another Title}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for the help, everyone!

Comment: As the unbiased original author of `memoir` I think that your answer is just the right thing.