# Center spacing of \section results in something's missing probably a missing \item

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sectioning

I tried to enter a second section to my report along with centering it, but whenever I center it, it end's up with something is missing.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[R]{Enzymatic Synthesis of Emollient Esters}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{Dept. of Chemical Eng., SCOE}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\parindent 0ex
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
 \section{ \textbf{ INTRODUCTION}}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\section{LITERATURE STUDY}\
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The formatting of section heading should be specified document wide preferably in the document class or failing that in the preamble, the heading shouldn't be inside `center` and should not contain `\textbf`

Comment: Perhaps you're interested in [Centering chapter/section/subsection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107281/5764)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[R]{Enzymatic Synthesis of Emollient Esters}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{Dept. of Chemical Eng., SCOE}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\parindent 0ex
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[center]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{SOME CHAPTER}

\lipsum[1]

 \section{INTRODUCTION}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{LITERATURE STUDY}
\lipsum[5-7]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks that pretty much solved my problem, on the other hand i also tried one more thing, i used the package sectsty, and a command of \sectionfont{\centering}, which solved my problem too

Comment: @RBK: Both work in this case. If you need to further customise your sections, chapters, &c., `titlesec` is much more powerful, and it has companion packages, `titleps` for headers and footers, which is simpler to use than `fancyhdr`, and `titletoc`, for table of contents, list of figures or tables, and the like.