# Putting the heading in the center

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I want to place the heading Hypersurfaces in the centre of the line.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=25mm,top=25mm,right=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent \LARGE{\textbf{Hypersurfaces}}\\ [0.3cm]
\large{\textbf{1. Defining equation}}\\
 In a 4d manifold, hypersurface is a 3d submanifold. It can be timelike, 
 spacelike or nulllike.\\
 $\Sigma$ is defined by
 \[\Phi(x^{\alpha})=0\]
 \[x^{\alpha}=x^{\alpha}(y^a)\]
```

How to move only one word in the center of the line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to use proper semantic notation when setting a document that you've started. Set the title inside a `center` environment, use `\section` for numbered sectional units and space out paragraphs using a blank line (not `\\`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \LARGE\bfseries Hypersurfaces
\end{center}

\section{Defining equation}

In a 4D manifold, hypersurface is a 3D submanifold. It can be timelike, space-like or null-like.

$\Sigma$ is defined by
\begin{gather}
  \Phi(x^{\alpha}) = 0 \\
  x^{\alpha} = x^{\alpha}(y^a)
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Once you have your code set up in a functional way, you can change the formatting in a uniform way. For example, if you want a period after the number in the sectional title, follow [How to add a dot after the section number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24439/5764).

Comment: But what if this is not the title of the document. If I want to make the heading of a section in the center, is it possible?

Comment: @Khushal: You'll probably want to be consistent. That is, not just *a* section heading, but *all* section headings. For that, see [Centering chapter/section/subsection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107281/5764).