# How to redefine a command in terms of its starred variant?

Tags: macros, starred-version

I am writing a lab report for a class. I want to redefine `\section` so that `\section{Analysis}` has the same output that `\section*{\centering Analysis}` would normally have. I tried

```
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\section*{\centering #1}}
```

but this causes an error. I am able to do

```
\newcommand{\newsection}[1]{\section*{\centering #1}}
```

to define a new command to do this, but it would be ideal if I could use the same `\section` command. I've seen several other questions about similar topics, but I don't understand the code so I can't quite adapt it to my example. My code would be something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

% redefine the command

\begin{document}

blah blah blah

\section{Analysis}

blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

Any help (regarding commands or any other aspects of my code that you find inappropriate) is appreciated.

Comment: This is a bad approach, have a look at the titlesec package instead.

Comment: Your idea doesn't work because `\section*` is not actually a command. The `*` in your input is treated as an optional first argument to the `\section` command. You can demonstrate that by seeing what happens if you input `\section  *  {my section title}` with spaces either side of the `*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things here:

1. Formatting

   If you want a consistent format for sectioning components, use a package that ties into that part of the document. I've used [`sectsty`](//ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) below. See [Centering chapter/section/subsection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107281/5764).
2. Redefinition

   Your redefinition is circular, since `\section` uses `\section`. Instead, copy `\section` into something else, say, `\oldsection` and then redefine `\section` using `\oldsection`. Something like

   ```
   \let\oldsection\section % Copy \section into \oldsection
   \renewcommand{\section}{\oldsection*} % \section is always starred
   ```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\centering}
\let\oldsection\section % Copy \section into \oldsection
\renewcommand{\section}{\oldsection*} % \section is always starred

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Analysis}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```